# Datagrid strange visual effects

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

Why does my `DataGrid` looks like this?
[image]

I have been adding some styles and I had some "side" effects. There are some lines missing, colouring isn't the same everywhere(lighter in the middle).
This is the xaml of the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" RowHeaderWidth="0"  CanUserResizeRows="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0" GridLinesVisibility="None" Height="400" Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Right" CanUserAddRows="True" Margin="0,210,0,0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Gray">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Mp3Title}" Width="300" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Download Info" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=DownloadProgress}" Width="250"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="State" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Width="250"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="80,0" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF181818"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                </DataGrid >
```

The cs part where I add the items in the textcolumns

```
GridInfo data = new GridInfo { Mp3Title = "Some item" ...etc... };
dataGrid.Items.Add(data);
```

Is it something in the styles messing it up?

Answer (score 2):

Your provided code as above seems fine. There maybe some definition for this likely as Window.Resources

Becomes lighter when clicked? Then, applying this might be useful.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFFDFD0A"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFFDFD0A"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

You can change the color as of your choice.

Or, the color becomes lighter without any input(click)? Can you explain more?

Comment: As you can see in the picture there is a difference in the colouring of the grid. Some are darker, other lighter. I will vote you up because your example gave me some ideas however I found the solution and make it a lot better. I will post an answer with a pic and the xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution and made it a lot better looking
[image]

xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" RowHeaderWidth="0"  CanUserResizeRows="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" Height="200" Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Right" CanUserAddRows="True" Margin="0,210,0,0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Gray" MouseEnter="dataGrid_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="dataGrid_MouseLeave">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Mp3Title}" Width="300" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Download Info" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=DownloadProgress}" Width="250"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="State" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Width="250"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Gray"/>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="80,10" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF181818"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                </DataGrid >
```

Comment: good to know you've found the solution. seems utilizing Mouse event. And as a tip, I think your DataGrid is not of what is needed to be edited by user, setting Readonly might be able you to avoid misuses by users. I'll also upvote your question. Hope you do great as always !